# Entity Framework 4.3 Migration Exception when Update-Database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

After upgrading from EF 4.2 and Migration to EF 4.3 and enabling migration,restarting Visual studio and everything , whenever I try to call Update-Database/Add-Migration I get this:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException:
>   The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[]
>   byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] 
>   namedParams)
>   at System.Management.Automation.ComMethod.InvokeMethod(PSMethod method, Object[] arguments)
>   Update-Database : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   At line:1 char:1
>       + update-database
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Exception has b... an invocation.:String) [Update-Database], RuntimeException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.,Update-Database

I tried cleaning the whole project , deleting ef and migration and packages folder and doing it from the beginning and still same error !

Anyone facing the same error? Or have a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you have context and migration in separate projects, you need to use -StartupProjectName "YourProject" option of add-migration and update-database

The [same error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/ab5102fd-cba5-4068-b2a4-ec3dcc2adfb6) was in 4.3 beta. I encountered it in 4.3 release as well.

Comment: I noticed this too. But a little different in my case.
I have my DbContext and Migrations in ONE project. But it is not the startup project. Adding -StartupProjectName solves this too. Really annoying to type this everytime.

Comment: Yeah Ef Team confirmed this which i find strange as builds before 4.3 didnt suffer from this !

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the Powershell commands, you can control the migration via code, and then tell it where your assembly and context are:

```
var configuration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration() {
  MigrationsAssembly = typeof(YourMigrations).Assembly,
  ContextType = typeof(YourContext)
};
```

Then you can either script it out or auto-run it by using the `DbMigrator` class:

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
var scripter = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
string script = scripter.ScriptUpdate(null, null);
```

Comment: im very interested in this can you please explain more ?

Comment: You might just want to check out [the MSDN documentation for DbMigrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator(v=vs.103).aspx)